# What is the runtime complexity of numpy's bit operation functions?

Tags: python, numpy, time-complexity

I happened to come across NumPy's bit operation functions like [bitwise_or](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html), [bitwise_and](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) and other bit operation functions. They are super fast. However, I wanted to know about their runtime complexity. Since it's an array, it must be at least O(N) right? Is there official documentation for this?

Comment: I'm sure it's O(N), but the multiplier is quite small.  Those map directly to machine language instructions.

Comment: "Since it's an array, it must be at least O(N) right? " Huh? What is N in your analysis?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga N is the total length of the array. Since you need to do it for every item in the array, I thought it must be O(N)

Comment: Yes, it is linear on the size of the array.